# Pdf annotation using SyncfusionPdf Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion, pdftron

can anyone know how to implement annotation in flutter app by using syncfusionpdf package?

I implemented but the annotation is not visible in my app. and also I can't edit the existing document page.

how about PDFTron package

Comment: "how about PDFTron package" Full annotation support comes out of the box with PDFTron WebViewer. See following two links. https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/ios/flutter and https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo
If you are having a particular issue with PDFTron please post full details/screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

| Query | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| can anyone know how to implement annotation in flutter app by using syncfusionpdf package? | We can able to add, remove and modify the annotations from the PDF document using Syncfusion Flutter PDF. Please find the documentation to do the same from https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-annotations. And please find the android studio sample from https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AnnotationsSample-535190409. Please find the feature list supported by Syncfusion Flutter PDF from https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/overview#key-features-of-syncfusion-flutter-pdf. |
| I can't edit the existing document page. | We can able to add text, images, headers and footers, lists, tables, bookmarks, document security and annotations in new and existing PDF document. But as of now we do not have support to remove or edit text and images in an existing PDF document. |
| I implemented but the annotation is not visible in my app. | We cannot able to reproduce this issue in our end. Please provide the below details to validate further in this. 1) Which viewer you are using to view the PDF document. 2) Device or browser details. 3) Sample output PDF document with added annotations |